# For each subfolder, sort files by name and rename them to sequential padded numbers (regardless of extension)

Tags: bash, rename, filenames, sort

I have the following directory structure:

```
.
├── event-a
│   ├── album-a
│   │   ├── a.jpg
│   │   └── x.png
│   └── album-b
│       ├── a.jpg
│       ├── x.png
│       └── y.gif
└── event-b
    ├── album-x
    │   ├── a.jpg
    │   └── x.png
    └── album-y
        ├── a.jpg
        ├── x.png
        └── y.gif
```

For each second-level subfolder (named `album-foo` in the example), I want to sort the files by name and rename them to sequential padded numbers, regardless of their extension. The folders may contain JPG, PNG or GIF images, and any file extensions should be preserved.

So, in this case, I’d like to get this result:

```
.
├── event-a
│   ├── album-a
│   │   ├── 01.jpg
│   │   └── 02.png
│   └── album-b
│       ├── 01.jpg
│       ├── 02.png
│       └── 03.gif
└── event-b
    ├── album-x
    │   ├── 01.jpg
    │   └── 02.png
    └── album-y
        ├── 01.jpg
        ├── 02.png
        └── 03.gif
```

[The `rename` utility](http://plasmasturm.org/code/rename/rename) may be used if that makes anything easier.

The main problem is figuring out the number each file should get. Do I need to use a nested `for` loop to iterate over the `event-x` and `album-x` subfolders, then for each inner loop, keep track of the number myself, or is there some clever solution that I’m missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
for dir in */*; do           # loop over the directories
    (                        # run in a subshell ...
        cd "$dir"            # ... so we don't have to cd back
        files=(*)            # store the filenames in a zero-indexed array

        for index in "${!files[@]}"; do
            file=${files[$index]}
            ext=${file##*.}
            newname=$(printf "%02d.%s" $((index+1)) "$ext")
            mv "$file" "$newname"
        done
    )
done
```

Suppose you have a file with no extension. In that case it will have the same name except with leading numbers (e.g. `my_file` => `05.my_file`)

All non-hidden directory entries will be renamed, including directories.

Comment: Thanks! FTR, a friend of mine wrote the following snippet which is very similar to your answer: https://gist.github.com/2471545

Comment: there is an open quote at `ext=...`

Comment: We can safely ignore [SC2164](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2164) on line 3?

Answer (score 3):

You have two sets of problems here:

1. Recursing into directories.
2. Restarting the numbering system within each separate directory.

This will handle both conditions smoothly, although you will want to modify the IMAGE_TYPES variable if you decide to include other extensions as well.

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob
shopt -s nocaseglob

IMAGE_TYPES='jpg|png|gif'
IFS=$'\n' dirlist=(`find "$PWD" -type d`)

for dir in "${dirlist[@]}"; do
    cd "$dir"
    ls *.+($IMAGE_TYPES) > /dev/null 2>&1 || continue

    counter=0
    for file in *.+($IMAGE_TYPES); do
        printf -v newname "%.3d.%s" $((counter += 1)) "${file##*.}"
        mv --verbose "$file" "$newname"
    done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I created the same tree and did your move build. Here's what I came up with:

```
n=0 IFS=.; set -f ./[e]vent*/*/*
for f do [ -n "${f##./\[*}" ] || break
    [ "$d" = "${f%/*}" ] || i=0 d=${f%/*}
    mv=': mv "${'$((n=$n+1))'}" "${'$n'%%/*}/'
    printf "$mv%.2d%.0s.%s\"\n" $((i=$i+1)) ${f##*/}
done | sh -sx -- "$@"
```

Without that last `|`pipe on the end there this is what it prints:

```
mv "${1}" "${1%/*}/01.jpg"
mv "${2}" "${2%/*}/02.png"
mv "${3}" "${3%/*}/01.jpg"
mv "${4}" "${4%/*}/02.png"
mv "${5}" "${5%/*}/03.gif"
mv "${6}" "${6%/*}/01.jpg"
mv "${7}" "${7%/*}/02.png"
mv "${8}" "${8%/*}/01.jpg"
mv "${9}" "${9%/*}/02.png"
mv "${10}" "${10%/*}/03.gif"
```

It doesn't look like much, I know, but what's important here is that you don't have to worry about any weird filenames or any of that - the intended destination for that output is a shell that shares a positional array with the `for` loop that generated it. I've got one such in the command there  - and it's configured to provide debug output, which looks like this:

```
+ : mv ./event-a/album-a/a.jpg ./event-a/album-a/01.jpg
+ : mv ./event-a/album-a/x.png ./event-a/album-a/02.png
+ : mv ./event-a/album-b/a.jpg ./event-a/album-b/01.jpg
+ : mv ./event-a/album-b/x.png ./event-a/album-b/02.png
+ : mv ./event-a/album-b/y.gif ./event-a/album-b/03.gif
+ : mv ./event-b/album-x/a.jpg ./event-b/album-x/01.jpg
+ : mv ./event-b/album-x/x.png ./event-b/album-x/02.png
+ : mv ./event-b/album-y/a.jpg ./event-b/album-y/01.jpg
+ : mv ./event-b/album-y/x.png ./event-b/album-y/02.png
+ : mv ./event-b/album-y/y.gif ./event-b/album-y/03.gif
```

That's what it looks like when the `:` is the first character in the `printf` format string. When I remove it and execute the command:

```
ls ./event*/*/

./event-a/album-a/:
01.jpg  02.png

./event-a/album-b/:
01.jpg  02.png  03.gif

./event-b/album-x/:
01.jpg  02.png

./event-b/album-y/:
01.jpg  02.png  03.gif
```

That appears to be inline with your request. You can't beat results, I guess.

Answer (score -1):

If you have the name of the file, you can get it's number by running:

```
ls -1 <your_dir> | grep <file_name> -B 1000 | wc -l
```

Comment: [Parsing the output of `ls` is not a good idea](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). It'll mostly work here, but a wildcard-based solution will completely work, so why settle for second-best?

Comment: "ls -1" give you only the file names if that's what you mean.

Comment: In most cases, yes. In general, no. Try (in bash/ksh/zsh) `touch junk precious $'junk\nprecious'; ls -1 | grep junk | xargs -l rm`. You didn't really care about that `precious` file, did you? Not to mention that restriction to at most 1000 files, or the fact that you find `03.jpg` when you're looking for `3.jpg`. I retract my comment for second-best, this is really broken, and it's incomplete to boot.